# Android studio 3.0 error....unable to merge multiple dex files

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

i have found that in packages under libraries/android/arch/lifecycle there are some files which have been created twice. Due to which I'm getting an error that unable to merge multiple dex files....And I'm not able to delete then...these are read only. Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Please share the logs and version of Android Studio you are using.

Comment: and your build.gradle.

Comment: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/Observer;

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: I'm repeating question because no one was able to help me with the correct solution. All the solutions they provided, i already knew and have tried. But still there was this error.